# Thread safety of copy on write

Tags: c++, multithreading, copy-on-write

I try to understand proper way of developing threadsafe applications.

In current project I have following class :

```
class Test
{
public:
    void setVal(unsigned int val)
    {
        mtx.lock();
        testValue = val;
        mtx.unlock();
    }

    unsigned int getVal()
    {
        unsigned int copy = testValue;
        return copy;
    }
private:
    boost::mutex mtx;
    unsigned int testValue;
}
```

And my question : is above method Test::getVal() threadsafe in multithreaded environment, or it must be locked before taking copy ?
I've read some articles about COW, and now I'm unsure.

Thanks!

Comment: It is not threadsafe. Even if you mark it as vilatile

Comment: What does this have to do with copy on write?

Comment: It's hard to tell from your current question: Are you aware that your code sample does not make use of copy-on-write at all? What you wrote is a simple concurrent access to a member variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have data which can be shared between multiple threads (such as the `testValue` member in your case), you *must* synchronise all accesses to that data. "Synchronise" has a broad meaning here: it could be done using a mutex, by making the data atomic, or by explicitly invoking a memory barrier.

But you cannot skip on this. In a parallel world with multiple threads, CPU cores, CPUs and caches, there is no guarantee that a write by one thread will be visible to another thread if they don't "shake hands" on a synchronisation primitive. It is quite possible that thread T1's cache entry for `testValue` will not be updated when thread T2 writes into `testValue`, precisely because the HW cache management system sees "no synchronisation is happening, the threads don't access shared data, why should I torpedo performance by invalidating caches?"

The C++11 standard chapter [intro.multithread] goes into more detail than you'd like on this, but here's an informal Note from that chapter summarising the idea:

> 5 ... Informally, performing a release operation on *A* forces prior side
>   effects on other memory locations to become visible to other threads that later perform a consume or an
>   acquire operation on *A.* ...